# How propagate HTMLAttributes to a custom EditorTemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, mvc-editor-templates

I created a Editor template for **currency** float format like this.

```
@using System.Globalization
@{
    var ri = new RegionInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID);
}

<div class="input-group ">
    <div class="input-group-addon">@ri.CurrencySymbol</div>
    @Html.TextBox("", ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model, new { @class = " form-control text-box single-line" })
</div>
```

which shows a bootstrap input group with currency symbol

[image]

It works fine, but im trying to pass some additional classes like "text-danger" or "input-group-lg" however those parameters are not passed to the Editor template.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.money, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "text-danger input-lg form-group-lg" } })
```

the classes "text-danger input-lg form-group-lg" are not set to the main div.

How can I propagate those classes to my Editor template?

Comment: You made this Editor for what type? (float, int, string)

Comment: You can try using ViewData like `(string)ViewData["ClassText"]` on the Template, `@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model, new { @class = " form-control text-box single-line " + (string)ViewData["ClassText"]` then on the editor for it would be like this `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.money, new { ClassText = "text-danger input-lg form-group-lg"  })`

Comment: @FelipeDeguchi float

Comment: You need to pass the attributes as `additionalViewData` (not `HtmlAttributes`) and read the `ViewData` in the `EditorTemplate` and add the values to you html.

Comment: I'm personally not a fan of passing css classes to Templates (EditorFor/DisplayFor).  What if your template is complex, what HTML nodes do you apply the values too?  It's ambiguous, and if you change the  template, what other templates/pages call that template, it's just a nightmare, so I never recommend doing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use route ViewData["htmlAttributes"] to a dictionary and get "class" value

```
@{
    var htmlAttrib = ViewData["htmlAttributes"]
    IDictionary<string, object> dic = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttrib);
    var classes = dic ["class"];
}

<div class="@classes" > your control .... </div>
```